# Log of lost internet connections

Tags: connection, ubuntu-mate, ping

I am having a big problem with lost internet connections with my DSL.

I would like to create a log to be able to show the technician when he comes next week.

I have this.

```bsh
while true; do
date >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
echo >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
ping  47.182.239.232 -c 1 >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
echo >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt
sleep 180
done
```

I would like for it to only log pings that generate 100% packet loss.
Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps: `ping -c1 47.182.239.232 | grep 100  >> Internet_Connection_Log.txt`

Comment: `journalctl $(type -p NetworkManager)` will show the logs the system already has.

Answer (score 0):

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Ubuntu_Mate 18.04 LTS
#-----------------------------------
# Internet log of connection failures
#

while : ; do
     if ! ping  -c 1 47.182.239.232 ; then
          printf "\n%s\n" "ping failed at $(date)" >> /home/andy/bin/Internet_Connection_FAILURES_Log.txt
          cvlc --play-and-exit /usr/share/sounds/My_Sounds/Alarm-sound-buzzer.mp3
     fi
     sleep 60
done
```